# Скомпоновать имя переменной

Tags: android, java

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fl1);
```

*Таким образом я могу выбрать fl1 в качестве image res.* Но мне вместо "1" надо подставить значение переменной i, т.е. если:

> i = 2, то мне надо сделать - imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fl2);
>
> i = 3, то мне надо сделать - imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fl3);
>
> и т.д.

**Как добиться такого эффекта?**

p.s. Первое что приходит в голову (разумеется не работает :))

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fl + i);
```

**UPDATE1** Не один из ответов не сработал. У [[@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets)](/users/3608/gorets) ресурс картинки просто не меняется, а у [[@system29a](/users/812/system29a)](/users/812/system29a) и у [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd):

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Map<Integer,Integer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("R.drawable.fl"+i, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
imgView.setImageResource(drawableResourceId);
```

Answer (score 4):

Я не знаю специфики Андроида, но могу предположить следующее:

1. Сделайте массив `flValues[]` и в ручную добавьте все значения переменных fl{i} тогда ваш вариант — `imgView.setImageResource(flValues[i])`
2. Можно использовать Reflection, но, думаю, это слишком мудрёно. Как вытащить значение поля по её имени смотрите [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html)

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, есть ли нативное решение, но почему бы не завести статический `Map<int, int> indexToResId` и просто писать

```
imgView.setImageResource(indexToResId[i]);
```

?

Comment: Пожалуйста дайте код, как завести этот Map<>

Просто совсем забыл как его использовать, а с ходу снова разобраться в нём не получилось :(

Comment: @danpetruk: как-то так:

    private final Map<Integer, Integer> indexToResId =
                  new HashMap<Integer, Integer>()
    {{
        put(1, R.drawable.fl1);
        put(2, R.drawable.fl2);
        put(3, R.drawable.fl3);
        // etc.
    }};

Если у вас индексы все подряд начиная с нуля, можно просто массив:

    private final List<Integer> indexToResId = Arrays.asList(
        R.drawable.fl0,
        R.drawable.fl1,
        R.drawable.fl2,
        R.drawable.fl3 // etc.
    );